# Розница выгружает на сайт каждую характеристику товара как отдельный товар

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, 1с

Необходимо соединить 1с Предприятие(8.3.18) конфигурация "розница"(2.3) с интернет-магазином на woocommerce через [этот](https://itgalaxy.company/software/wordpress-woocommerce-1c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8/woocommerce-1c%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81/) плагин.

Интернет магазин небольшой, пока что только 30 вариативных товаров. Задача на первый взгляд простая, все работает с обычными товарами, однако, при создании товара с характеристиками(вариативный товар), 1с выгружает каждую характеристику как отдельный товар. В документации к плагину есть [описание такой проблемы](https://itgalaxy.company/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/), но нет решения.

Часть файла offers.xml(узел "Предложения") с вариативным товаром, который 1с передает на сайт (id товара формируется сложный, а узла "ХарактеристикиТовара" нет):

```
<Предложения>
<Предложение>
<Ид>f156b7b5-7b8c-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6#d050b073-7b8d-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6</Ид>
<Артикул>555</Артикул>
<Наименование>Товар (Характеристика 1)</Наименование>
<БазоваяЕдиница Код="796" НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">
<Пересчет>
<Единица>796</Единица>
<Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
</Пересчет>
</БазоваяЕдиница>
<Цены>
<Цена>
<Представление> 270 RUB за шт</Представление>
<ИдТипаЦены>177e6622-7b8c-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6</ИдТипаЦены>
<ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>270</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
<Валюта>RUB</Валюта>
<Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
</Цена>
</Цены>
<Количество>50</Количество>
<Склад ИдСклада="f156b7a2-7b8c-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6" КоличествоНаСкладе="50"/>
</Предложение>
<Предложение>
<Ид>f156b7b5-7b8c-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6#d050b074-7b8d-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6</Ид>
<Артикул>555</Артикул>
<Наименование>Товар (Характеристика 2)</Наименование>
<БазоваяЕдиница Код="796" НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">
<Пересчет>
<Единица>796</Единица>
<Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
</Пересчет>
</БазоваяЕдиница>
<Цены>
<Цена>
<Представление> 135 RUB за шт</Представление>
<ИдТипаЦены>177e6622-7b8c-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6</ИдТипаЦены>
<ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>135</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
<Валюта>RUB</Валюта>
<Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
</Цена>
</Цены>
<Количество>20</Количество>
<Склад ИдСклада="f156b7a2-7b8c-11eb-ab7a-00e04c901cb6" КоличествоНаСкладе="20"/>
</Предложение>
</Предложения>
```

Пробовал на других версиях программы, ничего не меняется.

Из-за чего такое может быть? Как можно все-таки связать 1с(Розницу или УТ) с Woocommerce?.

Comment: Вам необходимо: сравнить xml товара который успешно загружается и xml товара с характеристикой; найти различия; Затем написать скрипт который приводит xml с характеристиками к виду который успешно загружается; Прогонять xml через свой скрипт, и затем загружать в магазин

Answer (score 0):

В общем, помогла [эта статья](https://coderstar.ru/kurs-ut11/harakteristiki-nomenklatury)(**читать после заголовка "Использование нескольких свойств в характеристике**"). Оказывается, плагин для соединения wooCommerce и 1С работает только с характеристиками, которые имеют свойства.